# Ajuda: Valorizar um vetor de char de uma struct dentro de um if

Tags: c++, if, struct, array, char

Estou tentando definir o valor de um vetor de char de uma struct dentro de um if, mas sem sucesso...

**A struct propriamente dita:**

```
    struct ficha {
        char nome[31], classificacao[31], telefone[21];
        float altura, peso, imc;
    }paciente1, paciente2, aux;
```

Seguem-se as tentativas:

**Tenttiva 1:**

```
    if (paciente1.imc<18.5) {
        paciente1.classificacao = {"Abaixo do peso", 31};
    } else if ...
```

**Tentativa 2:**

```
    if (paciente1.imc<18.5) {
        paciente1.classificacao = "Abaixo do peso";
    } else if ...
```

**Tentativa 3:**

```
    if (paciente1.imc<18.5) {
        paciente1.classificacao = ("Abaixo do peso", [31]);
    } else if ...
```

Desde já grato pela ajuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não me engano, não é possível setar o conteúdo de um array diretamente assim, tem que setar o conteúdo de suas posições. A função `strcpy` pode te ajudar:

```
if (paciente1.imc<18.5) {
    strcpy(paciente1.classificacao, "Abaixo do peso");
} else if ...
```

Comment: Obrigado @Pedro Lorentz, solucionou o problema !!